# Iteration over a users timeline of twitter tweets with egg_mode crate

Tags: twitter, rust

I am using the rust egg_mode crate for iterating over a users timeline of tweets and find if they posted a required tweet for a comp. Now I have pretty much have it all working however I cant workout how I would handle this code in a loop.

I might not be using the egg_mode api correctly but am unsure.

```
    let (timeline, feed) = timeline.start().await?;
    loop {
        for tweet in feed.iter() {
            let (tfound, mfound) = check_tweet(tweet).await?;
            tweets_checked += 1;

            // Return if both are found.
            if tweet_found && media_found {
                let id = tweet.id as i64;
                return Ok((tweet_found, media_found, id, tweets_checked));
            }
        }
        let (timeline, feed) = &timeline.older(None).await?;
    }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `timeline`
   --> src/check_twitter/main.rs:145:33
    |
125 |     let (timeline, feed) = timeline.start().await?;
    |          -------- move occurs because `timeline` has type `egg_mode::tweet::Timeline`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
145 |         let (timeline, feed) = &timeline.older(None).await?;
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^ ----------- `timeline` moved due to this method call, in previous iteration of loop
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `timeline`
   --> /home/utx0/.cargo/git/checkouts/egg-mode-01a8f29f644cee57/6b81073/src/tweet/mod.rs:520:18
    |
520 |     pub fn older(self, since_id: Option<u64>) -> TimelineFuture {
    |                  ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Working solution is:

```
    let (mut timeline, mut feed) = timeline.start().await?;
    loop {
        let mut id: u64 = 0;
        for tweet in feed.iter() {
            let (tfound, mfound) = check_tweet(tweet).await?;
            tweets_checked += 1;

            id = tweet.id;

            if tfound == true {
                tweet_found = tfound;
                tweet_id = tweet.id as i64;
            }

            if mfound == true {
                media_found = mfound;
            }

            // Return if both are found.
            if tweet_found && media_found {
                let id = tweet.id as i64;
                return Ok((tweet_found, media_found, id, tweets_checked));
            }
        }
        let (ntimeline, nfeed) = timeline.older(Some(id)).await?;
        timeline = ntimeline;
        feed = nfeed;
    }
```